# Word for "evaluating only the necessary components"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I am looking for a noun whose definition resembles "evaluating only the necessary components".

This is for our research, Chapter 3 under Ethical Considerations. The first two on the list are Beneficence, and Confidentiality.

I am looking for a single word (as much as possible) to parallel the first two on  the list.

Comment: The following are the ethical considerations followed while conducting the study: Beneficence, Confidentiality, and Evaluating only the relevant components.

Comment: It is unclear why you think that 'evaluating only the relevant components' is an **ethical** consideration.

Answer (score -1):

*Criteria*

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/criteria) :

> Criteria is the plural of criterion—a standard or principle for judging, **evaluating**, or selecting something. Criteria are the ideals or requirements on which a judgment, **evaluation**, or selection is based.

In your case it could be:

> *The inclusion criteria are average scores above 3 for beneficence and confidentiality.*